# Why are subviews of content view in ios tableview not respecting auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, storyboard

I have a button in the middle of UITableCell View even thought it appears centered in my storyboard and no errors when I run it on simulator it not position correctly

Here is a snapshot of my storyboard

[image]

and here is a snapshot of my simulator

[image]

Comment: Is your table view constrained correctly?

Comment: my table view is constrained yes

Comment: Try using the debug view hierarchy or changing the background colours of your tableview and cells to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks I think it xcode problem i cleaned and restarted my project and it worked fine